# HDMI sound output works on one account but not on the other

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I am running

- Ubuntu LTS 18.04
- SLiM
- Gnome 3

[On one account, sound works as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWyes.png).
Calling `pacmd list-cards` on this account returns

```
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfeaf8000 irq 19"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fb9"
        device.product.name = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#0: GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#0: Monitor of GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "SAMSUNG
     "
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfcff4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5560, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

[On another account, I see only the device "Dummy Output" listed in settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeoDw.png)
Calling `pacmd list-cards` on this account returns

```
0 card(s) available.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Same basic issue here, but with Ubuntu MATE 19.10.

At one point, doing

pulseaudio -k

was getting it undisabled / even appearing in the device list but at the moment, that's not happening. It also affects, but not as often, the main account.

pacmd list-cards on the account that can see it:

https://pastebin.com/zLsK8XfS

and on the one that can't:

https://pastebin.com/hm3GG70z

There's a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1853374 with output of pa-info